# How do I get the featured post to share on Social Media and show on Individual Post pages?

Tags: php, posts, functions, images

I could really use some help. I'm using the Hurricane Wordpress Theme. The one complaint I have is that the theme won't automatically include the featured image in the post's page, itself. The image is included when viewing a list of posts, though.

I could just add the image above the blog of text again (which is tedious), but the problem with that is that when I share the post on social media, no image is included. And we all know that images grab attention better than blocks of text. I know very little about how to edit the theme to make it do this. If someone could help, I'd seriously appreciate it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As for getting the the featured image to display in every post, you'll need to modify the theme directly (bad idea), or create a child theme and echo the featured image automatically using something like the_post_thumbnail() inside your single.php file.

As for showing the images when the posts are shared on social media, you need to set up Open Graph meta tags on your pages. This can be done automatically using a plugin like Complete Open Graph. It'll work out-of-the-box and use your featured images, but you can also set a specific OG image per page if you want.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/